# Boolean algebra - prove $x_1 = x_2$

Tags: proof-explanation, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to prove that two boolean algebra expressions are equivalent:

$x_1 = a'b'c + bc' + ac + ab'c$

$x_2 = b'c + bc’ + ab$

I got up to here:

LHS

$a'b'c + bc' + ac + ab'c$

RHS

$= (a + a')c + bc' + ab$

$= ab'c + a'b'c + bc' + ab$

$= a'b'c + bc' + ab'c + ab(c + c')$

$= a'b'c + bc' + ab'c + abc + abc'$

$= a'b'c + bc' + ab'c + (b + b')abc + abc'$

$= a'b'c + bc' + ab'c + abbc + ab'bc + abc'$

The next step is supposed to be

$= a'b'c + bc' + ab'c + ac + ab'c$

But I really can't see how they got to that step...

Someone please help me figure this one out and you will be a lifesaver thank you. Also let me know if I'm missing anything...

Comment: Still haven’t figured this out...

Comment: It doesn't look to me like it can be a single step.. by the way you do need the rest of the expression, abb′c+abbc+abc′=ac+ab′c is not true, so you can't just take that in isolation

Comment: Oh hmm thank you, I’ve removed that. The strange thing is the incomplete solution I checked with jumped to the last step written here all of a sudden, so I assumed...but these expressions still makes no sense to me. Of course that step solution could’ve been off from the first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for your first expression is:

```
             bc
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
a     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

You can convince yourself that the second expression has the same map.
Therefore, they are both equivalent.

A similar test would be to write a truth table for both expressions and compare the output columns.

Comment: Deleting old comment, never mind this method is actually very valid...my apologies for going all rookie earlier on.